# How to distinguish between “however” and “whenever”?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have this sentence:

> Even if it takes forever, I am going to speak English like a native.

What I want to know is whether the first part of the sentence would be better replaced by *whenever* or *however*:

> Even if it takes forever

My teacher says that *whenever* is the better option here, but I think it better to use *however* instead because I understand that the speaker wants to speak English at any price.

What is your opinion?

Comment: "Forever" is the correct word in that sentence, and you should **not** replace it with either "whenever" or "however".  If you want to completely rephrase the statement, you could *start* it with "whatever", as in "*Whatever* it takes, I'm going to learn to speak English like a native".

Comment: Well, the goal was replace the first statement with some word ending with `-ever`. I feel more confused now ¬¬

Comment: Your assignment is ill-posed. If you're not allowed to restructure the sentence, and must simply fill the blank in "Even if it takes ___, I am...", with a word ending in "-*ever*", then then only possible candidate is "forever". If you're allowed to rearrange the sentence, then there are any number of possibilities. For just one, simple example: "Learning a foreign language is very difficult; *however*, I'm committed to learning to speak English like a native."

Comment: I need to replace all the sentence: "Even if it takes forever".

Comment: Then say "***Whatever** it takes*", as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It seems the most suitable option.

Comment: Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Comment: @choster I'm still having difficulty persuading someone _here_ that 'Whenever, I am going to speak English like a native' should not be considered standard English. It's difficult proving a negative.

Comment: Addressing the second clause, shortening it to "I *will* speak..." is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the option to recreate the phrase *Even if it takes forever* and use multiple words you can acceptably use either *whenever* or *however*.  For instance:

1. "*Whenever it happens*, I am going to speak English like a native."
2. "*However long it takes*, I am going to speak English like a
          native."

However, if you tried to use only a single word, either *whenever* or *however*, then either would in most cases sound cluncky to a native ear.  Also, *however* changes meaning when used as a single word to start a sentence.  In this case, *however* signifies a contrast.  I can say:

"You predicted I will never learn to speak English well.  However, I am going to learn to speak English like a native.  Then you will see how wrong you were."

But I couldn't use "*however*" as a single word to start a sentence if I wasn't making a contrast.  In your example, you cannot know that something exists to make that contrast; therefore, *however* as a single word is not appropriate.

*Whenever* can be used as a single word at the beginning of a sentence and when so used can retain its meaning of "no matter when" or (used informally) "at an unknown or unspecified time" - both definitions from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whenever).

It's more common by native speakers to use a single word *whenever* at the end of a sentence, such as "I'll do that *whenever*" the same way one can say "I'll do that happily." But as always allowed in English, the adverb can be moved to the beginning of the sentence.  It is possible to say, "Whenever, I'll do that" just as it's possible to say "Happily, I'll do that."

There's a recent hit song by Shakira that uses *whenever* in this way:

> "Whenever, wherever, we're meant to be together."

Shakira's not a native English speaker but I think this line sounds acceptable to a native ear.

Also commonly heard in English is the single word *whenever* when the rest of the sentence is understood.  I doubt any native English speaker would have a problem with this dialogue:

```
A:  "When should I pay you back?"
B:  "Whenever."
```

But technically the full sentence is "Whenever [you pay me back]."  So while most native speakers may not be accustomed to hearing *whenever* at the beginning of longer sentence and, thus, it sounds wrong to them, they actually hear *whenever* used in this way with understood sentences all the time.  Let's try again:

```
A:  "When are you going to to speak English like a native?"
B:  "Whenever."
```

Again, no one would have protested this use because this form is so commonly heard.  **But the full, understood second sentence is "Whenever [I am going to speak English like a native]."**  Which means that had you said the full, understood sentence, you would have been **correct** even though it might have grated on native ears that are not used to hearing the full, understood sentences.

Comment: 'However' is a well known contrastive sentence connector, often used as an introductory phrase parenthetical. However, I've found no confirmation that a similar usage of the word 'whenever' is considered standard English. Your Collins reference does not license this usage. Can you back up your claim '"Whenever" can be used as a single word at the beginning of a sentence'?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don't think that line from the Shakira song works if remove either of the two words, but they seem to work okay in tandem. Consequently, I might be tempted to punctuate is like this: _Whenever, wherever – we're meant to be together._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth as explained in my answer the Collins reference was used merely to provide definitions.  It also notes the word *whenever* using those definitions is an adverb.  Do you want me to post a source saying it's ok to begin a sentence with an adverb?  See [GrammarBuilder textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=DsKeOwh7Nu0C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=definite+time+adverb+beginning+of+a+sentence&source=bl&ots=8Jt_LGXsZB&sig=FMbbTJiVOOohoZ2OK9U8jLdR-8U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BDIHVJzkDNe-ggSMuoCADQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=definite%20time%20adverb%20beginning%20of%20a%20sentence&f=false)

Comment: There are many adverbs and words looking like adverbs that can be used to start sentences. I want you to post a source saying that a sentence may be started by 'Whenever' followed by a comma, as an introductory parenthetical. My second sentence above gives an example using 'However,' which is traditionally a 'linking adverb', not a 'subordinating conjunction' like 'whenever' [as shown in this ABA article](http://www.abaenglish.com/blog/english-grammar-learn-english-with-aba/english-grammar-an-introduction-to-sentence-connectors/). This puts 'whenever' in the same class as say 'until'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *until* is not an adverb.  It is a preposition.  It can also be a conjunction, but it can't be an adverb.  Therefore, your comment that *whenever* is in the same class as *until* is incorrect. Also, i am not talking about adverbs used as *linking adverbs* or used as *subordinating conjunctions*. From Collins it is clear I am referring to to definitions of *whenever* as an adverb not as a *subordinating conjuction* (separate definition).  Also in the grammar book in my comment above, an adverb of this type can be at the beginning of a sentence.  What's not clear?

Comment: 'However' can be used as a [sentence connector](http://www.zaneeducation.com/education/literary-arts/sentence-connectors-and-interjection.php): _It was raining. However, I had my waterproof with me._ 'Whenever' can't: _I'd been trying for three weeks. *Whenever, I was going to do it._ Read Dan Bron's first comment and J.R.'s first sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, again, I'm not talking about *sentence connectors*.  I'm talking about simple, single-word adverbs.  Any simple, single-word adverb relating to time and frequency can be placed at the beginning of a sentence, as demonstrated in the grammar book I cited.

Comment: That book actually mentions the fact that 'seldom' can't: "Seldom she attends our club meetings. **X** "  Turning to 'whenever': the only use of the wh-word 'whenever' at the beginning of a sentence given by your Collins reference is "Whenever did he escape?" (= "When on earth did he escape?"). This is **not** 'whenever [being] used as a single word at the beginning of a sentence'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth true but you're quibbling. *Whenever*, used as a single-word adverb with the definitions I cited and per the question, is an adverb of time not frequency.  So *seldom* isn't comparable and you see the grammar book has different rules for adverbs of time versus frequency.  As also stated in [EnglishGrammarOnline](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position) "Adverbs of time are usually put at the end of the sentence.  If you don't want to put emphasis on the time, you can also put the adverb of time at the beginning of the sentence."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I will further cite [Amorey Gethin](http://www.lingua.org.uk/posadv.html), author of numerous published books on the English language, who states "A reader asked about the basic rules of word order for adverbs and adverbial clauses in written English. In fact, one cannot really speak of rules in this connection. There are only certain conventions of common usage.....adverbs of practically any sort can be put at the beginning of the sentence, for emphasis."  Now I've provided you multiple sources.  Please provide even one that supports your position.

Comment: Gethrin doesn't cover this specific case. And read the whole quote; you've quoted selectively. // I've posted the question about the acceptability of the 'used as a single word at the beginning of a sentence' 'whenever' usage on [englishforums.com](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WheneverUsedAsAnAdverb/bhddwj/post.htm) and was delighted to see that CalifJim responded. Examination of his other posts shows his mastery of English usage.

Comment: ... Is it acceptable to start a sentence with the word 'whenever' used as an adverb?

One day, I'll master this language.

Whenever, I'll master this language.
**Reply**
CalifJim:

No. That doesn't work at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't believe I have to clarify this but when I asked you to provide a source to support your claim that *whenever* cannot be used to start a sentence, I meant one comparable to the multi-published author of English language books I cited, not some unknown guy on the Internet. How do we know he's not your brother, or you under another handle?  Seriously, this is the best source you can come up with?  Because that's no source at all and I can't believe you're still arguing this when you can't find a single scrap of a legitimate source to support your argument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't concede some adverbs can't go at the beginning of a sentence.  *Never/seldom* did I go to the cinema. Because both never and seldom have negative meanings, it is normal to invert the subject and verb word order when they being a sentence, especially with a do/did verb.  But they definitely can begin a sentence.  As Gethin correctly states, any adverb can be used at the beginning of a sentence.  Children are taught rules on usage of adverbs per the grammar book but these are not really rules, just common usage, and expert writers know that any adverb can begin a sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seldom/never can also be used at the beginning of a sentence without a subject-verb inversion when not using a do/did verb.  "But seldom, I allow..." (published in The Europoean Magazine by The Philological Society of London, Volume VXVI, Oct. 1804, p. 264). "Seldom I laugh and seldom I ever cry" - Merle Haggard. "The majority is never right. Never, I tell you! - Henrik Ibsen, *An Enemy of the People*

Comment: Amazing discussion.

Comment: I suggest you read 'The distributional freedom and restriction of adverbs' (Rhanghyeyun Kim; Korea University) (available as a PDF) in which Kim claims that 'As observed in Jackendoff (1972), Travis (1988), and Cinque (1999), the free distribution of adverbs is only apparent, that is, the distribution of adverbs is in fact fairly restricted, even if there remain some residual cases of the free distribution.' He gives *'Completely George read the book' and *'Hard John hit Bill' as obvious counter-examples to a general 'any adverb can be used to start a declarative sentence' claim.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your quotation shows debate: some in support of "free distribution of adverbs", some liking restrictions.  The phrase *completely, he read the book* sounds awkward only because one would normally say "he read a(n) entire/complete (adjective) book" not "he read completely (adverb) a book".  So this is a disingenuous example.  The other example is pre-Yoda. "Hard to see the dark side is" is probably more recognizable to most English speakers than naming the last 5 Presidents.  Ultimately your source admits a general principal of "free distribution" and doesn't exclude *whenever*.

Comment: Ultimately 'my source' concludes 'In sum, the distribution of adverbs [is] fairly restricted, contrary to the claim of some linguists that adverbs are freely distributed and adverb movement is responsible for the free distribution of adverbs'. Do you even believe yourself?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Really?  You just falsified that quotation?  Here's what I see under his paper's [Summary and Conclusion](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elsok.org%2Fxe%2Faddons%2Fdoc_viewer%2Fdoc_viewer.php%3Fuploaded_filename%3D%2Fhome%2Felsok.org%2Fwww%2Fxe%2F.%2Ffiles%2Fattach%2Fbinaries%2F87285%2F363%2F087%2Fde6cd15bc5037b5d5f835b5dc801929a%26filename%3D17-1-11.pdf%26file_size%3D212142&ei=B-QIVImHBNXbsATyn4Io&usg=AFQjCNEpoCSZYL2S0YSPnTKN-jnjvTv6Gg):

Comment: "I have shown that the distribution of adverbs is fairly restricted with respect to other sentential elements and also among themselves. Among the various analyses on the distribution of adverbs, this paper looked over Cinque (1999) in detail, pointing out problems. I proposed that the distribution of adverbs can best be captured by a semantic-syntactic approach based on the semantic scope relation, the mapping hypothesis, and the phase theory (Chomsky 2000). The current analysis is free of the syntactic cost that is paid by Cinque (1999)."

Comment: "More research is in need in the future on the other types of adverbs and the kinds of semantic arguments they select."

Comment: First, poor grammar like "and also among themselves", "this paper looked over Cinque", "more research is in need in the future" abounds throughout the paper.  Second, the whole paper is 1st person, written by a non-native-speaker from Korea.  His level of writing and understanding are both below native speaker University level.  Third, as stated in his last sentence, his paper doesn't do any serious analysis on many types of adverbs (such as adverbs of time).  As you present this horrible source and falsify its comments you ask me if I even believe myself?  Do you?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a specific endorsement by any authority of the acceptability of the "Whenever, I am going to speak English like a native" = "However long it takes, I am going to speak English like a native" construction. You haven't provided one. Obviously, I'm having difficulty showing that it's not standard English; I'm only able to find support for the 'the distribution of adverbs is in fact fairly restricted' generalism (I trust Jackendoff is an acceptable authority here). Suffice it to say that examples on say Google are extremely rare (I haven't found any other than the lyric).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you falsified your quotation.  You have no credible sources.  You aren't interested in getting to the truth because then you'd have to admit I'm right - you're just arguing for the sake of it and making up quotations and using jokes for sources because you have no legitimate ones. I'm not interested in continuing with anyone like you who falsifies quotations.

Comment: This is certainly in the paper: "this paper argues that adverbs do not move and further shows that the distribution of adverbs [is] in fact very restricted as observed in Jackendoff (1972), Travis (1988), and Cinque (1999)". I was apparently quoting a secondary source I have on hard drive, but the thrust is identical. Are you going to argue against Jackendorf's analyses? Can you find a source sanctioning the specific usage in question here (rather than Gethin's '**in many contexts** (oops!), adverbs of practically any sort can be put at the beginning of the sentence, for emphasis:')?

Comment: The quote/s _should_ read:  'this paper argues that adverbs do not move and further shows that the distribution of adverbs [is] in fact very restricted ...'

'Contrary to the argument of some linguists that adverb movement results in the free distribution of adverbs, in this 
section I will give two pieces of evidence against adverb 
movement ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you've falsified your quotations, which is the end of our discussions, because you can't be trusted. There's no link to the Jackendoff paper for us to review, so we have only your (untrustworthy) word and the interpretation of a barely literate foreign student.  There's no evidence that Jackendoff even includes adverbs of time in his study, and no evidence Jackendoff says there's any restrictions to putting adverbs of time at the beginning of a sentence.  In short, you have *no valid sources*, and by posting falsified quotations you also have *no credibility*.  We're done.

Comment: I apologise for the unintentional misquote. Obviously, what was misquoted still conveyed the same opinions of the author; it was merely a mis-splicing. Now, can you explain why you chopped Gethin's 'in many contexts' off 'in many contexts , adverbs of practically any sort can be put at the beginning of the sentence, for emphasis', and how this can be used to justify your ' But as always allowed [sic] in English, the adverb can be moved to the beginning of the sentence.'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you falsified your quotation.  I didn't.  You see the five dots I have?  Those indicate I omitted words I deemed unimportant.  I deemed "in many contexts" unimportant because I wanted to know if it was *possible* to put any adverb at the beginning of a sentence not if it was *possible in every context*.  I have a legitimate, credible source that says it's possible in at least one context, in fact *many*.  You have no legitimate sources.  You have a foreign college student who writes poorly and a secondary source he interprets, but no proof it even refers to adverbs of time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth also that particular part of the quotation was, in my opinion, the far less important part.  What you have consistently chosen to ignore is the far more important part, that "for adverbs and adverbial clauses in written English.....one cannot really speak of rules.....There are only certain conventions of common usage." (longer quotation already cited above).  Since there really are no rules per se, only conventions, then there's no rule against putting any adverb at the beginning of sentence.  Even the researchers you cite only point to conventions, not rules.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your willingness to use a falsified quotation is ample evidence to me that you are not serious about getting to the truth of things, only about making (even knowingly false) arguments.  There's no reason for me to continue.  Your attempts to explain are entirely inadequate, because it's not like you forgot to type a word or misspelled something.  You co-joined parts from different paragraphs, out of order, and presented them as a single quotation.  And all this from a source you should have been ashamed to present in the first place because the paper is so poorly written.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing 'Even if it takes forever,' with 'However,' causes no problems grammatically, but the meaning is changed drastically. There would be an even more serious problem if the preceding context did not provide contrast: 'however' could not justifiably be used.

After checking, I've come across no modern treatments that accept 'whenever' as a 'conjunctive adverb' or 'sentence introducing pragmatic marker'. Even if it was ever used as such, I would not advise that it be used today by anyone who wants 'to speak English like a native' (of England). It might be used as a sentence substitute in a very colloquial / slang register:

> 'I'm busy this week; will next week do?'
>
> 'Oh, whenever!'

At [grammarquizzes](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-12.html) there's a lot of useful material on 'wh-ever phrases' (and clauses). Note that only 'however' = 'but', and dismissive slang 'Whatever!', are used outside a larger structure.

I'd say that the way an anglophone would most probably put it is:

> 'However long it takes, I am going to speak French like a native.'

..........................

I've been doing some further digging around this subject. CGEL is only marginally helpful here:

> Only rather broad and approximate flexible generalisations about
>   adjunct placement and sequence can be made. There is a great deal of
>   variation in use, and features of context, style, prosody and euphony
>   play a role in some decisions.

I posted this question on a different website:

> A dispute has arisen concerning the acceptability of [a fronted
>   unaccompanied usage of 'whenever':]
>
> Whenever, I'll be going back to Bryce. (= some day, ...)
>
> Do you consider this (1) a standard English usage, (2) slang, (3)
>   totally unacceptable?
>
> Is that based on (1) feel for English, (2) a rule of thumb, or (3) a
>   reference in a standard grammar unequivocally
>   licensing/flagging/proscribing the usage?

I received the reply, which I think essentially shows that the original is not the sort of question that learners should be exposed to never mind be expected to answer:

> Since (3), "totally unacceptable", rarely enters my head as a
>   linguistic category for something used by real (native) speakers, I
>   propose (4), "extremely unconventional".
>
> On the basis of (1), i.e. I have never heard it and would have
>   difficulty grasping the meaning in speech.
>
> If it is used, it is used. I will learn to live happily alongside it,
>   in which case it may move from (4) to (2), or even (1).   Phil White

Answer (score 1):

I could see using *whenever* in the sentence, but only if you reword it a little bit and turn it into a question:

> *Whenever am I going to speak English like a native?*

That construct could be used to indicate exasperation, and aligns with [Definition #4 at Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whenever):

> **whenever** (*adv.*) an intensive form of when, used in questions ⇒ *whenever did he escape?*

Assuming that:

- (a) you are going to retain this part of the sentence word-for-word:

> *I am going to speak English like a native*.

- (b) you want to change the entire clause at the beginning:

> *Even if it takes forever*,

- and (c) you don't want to change the meaning of the original,

then I don't think either of your one-word options is a good fit. You might try one of these:

> *[Someday](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/someday), I am going to speak English like a native*.
>   *One day, I am going to speak English like a native*.
>   *[Eventually](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eventually), I am going to speak English like a native*.